# Convert the SOM to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssom, spaudit, spauditeventtype, pnp-powershell

Can any one help me the conversation of below code to Power-Shell

```
 SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev");
        SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(site);

        query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));
        query.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
        SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = site.Audit.GetEntries(query);

        foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.EventName);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;       
    $spSite=Get-SPSite -Identity "http://sp/sites/dev" 
    $spwWeb=$spSite.OpenWeb() 
    $spAuditQuery=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($spSite)
    $Today = [DateTime]::Today
    $DateLimit = $Today.AddDays(-7)
    $spAuditQuery.SetRangeStart($DateLimit)
    $spAuditQuery.SetRangeEnd(($Today))
    $spAuditEntries=$spSite.Audit.GetEntries($spAuditQuery) 
    foreach($spAuditEntry in $spAuditEntries){ 
        Write-Host $spAuditEntry.EventName
    } 
    $spwWeb.Dispose()      
    $spSite.Dispose()
```

I guess you are querying site audit logs. Maybe [this link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-read-the-Audit-Log-1fce8b62) helps you.

Comment: Dear I am getting the Error as "GetSiteUserByID : The term 'GetSiteUserByID' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Changed code. This is working fine for me. I guess exact same code for your SOM code.